# how to remove cloud values of Landsat image from R

Tags: r, modis, landsat-8, cloud-gis

How can I remove cloud value of the Landsat8? How can I estimate cloud values  for eg: modis cloud values are from 700 to 800. By using R how can I estimate>

Comment: Do you want to remove cloud from landsat or from modis?

Comment: i need for landsat8 sir

Answer (score 4):

The best established Landsat cloud detection algorithm used today is [**fmask**](https://code.google.com/p/fmask/) published by [Zhu&Woodcock](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425711003853).

It is not written in R but in MATLAB, it can be downloaded as MATLAB code or as a compiled C executable. The source code however is openly available, so you could try to rewrite it in R (ceholden already did it for [python](https://github.com/ceholden/config_fmask)).

Comment: Progress is being made on a R version of F-mask: https://bitbucket.org/droletg/fmask

Comment: Simply run `devtools::install_bitbucket("droletg/fmask.git")` to install the R package as long as it is not on CRAN. All required functionality (i.e., cloud, cloud shadow, and snow mask) is included in the function `fmask`.

Answer (score 2):

If you order your data through the USGS Earth Explorer via the USGS ESPA application you can use the issued cloud mask file with ending 'cfmask' or 'sr_cloud' (depending on which product you use).

These files simply contain bit keys for cloud presence. You cloud for example query these values with an if-statement and use the resulting dataframe as a mask in R.